# Template path hints only show on backend using Magento

Tags: magento, frontend

I enabled the template paths hints on Magento, but I can only see it on the admin page, I can not see it on the frontend. A theme has been used. And the Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Anyone have a solution for this? Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do with it using SQL query just try with below

You can turn them off by running the following query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '1' WHERE path LIKE '%template_hints%';
```

After running the query make sure you clean the var/cache directory too when you are in the

Magento root. (rm -rf var/cache/*)

Also see this [free extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html)

i am not associate with above link it is just for your help

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @XinruiMa,glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache or disable it and reload the page with Ctrl+F5. I think that will be ok..
If you want to make more changes keep all the cache disabled.

Comment: Sorry, but I did that and it also only show on admin page, not frontend page.

Comment: Ok.Did you try to enable it from the backend? You can enable template path hints for the front end from the admin panel.Just notice that you have to select the correct store view from the drop-down menu. If you enabled the template path hints with this code: `INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');` you will be able to see it on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

go to phpmyadmin

execute below query

```
SELECT *
FROM `core_config_data`
WHERE `path` LIKE '%hints%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**enable template hint in frontend**

set value & scope_id = 1

```
for following path

dev/debug/template_hints

dev/debug/template_hints_blocks
```

**enable template hint in backend**
set value= 1 & scope_id = 0

```
for following path

dev/debug/template_hints

dev/debug/template_hints_blocks
```

you can disable template hints by setting value=0 for both frontend & backend